# Variable to use across iOS app

Tags: objective-c, integer

How can I set an `integer` that can be called from any ViewController in the iOS app?

example:

**FirstViewController**

```
int n;
n = 1;
```

SecondViewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    n = 3;
}
```

ThirdViewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
n=4
}
```

**ForthViewController**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
int a =0;

    a=n+10;
    }
```

When the user enters the `ThirdViewController` and then `ForthViewController`. The `int` a int the `ForthViewController` will be a=14.

Comment: put int n in Delegate file.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a singleton for example:

.h file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SelectedView : NSObject {
NSInteger number;
}
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger number;

+ (SelectedView *) instance;

@end
```

your .m file

```
#import "SelectedView.h"

@implementation SelectedView

@synthesize number;

static SelectedView *sharedNumber = nil;

+ (SelectedView *)instance {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if(sharedNumber == nil)
            sharedNumber = [[self alloc] init];
    }

return sharedNumber;
}

+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if(sharedNumber == nil) {
            sharedNumber = [super allocWithZone:zone];

            return sharedNumber;
        }
    }

    return nil;
}

- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    return self;
}

- (id)retain {
    return self;
}

- (unsigned)retainCount {
    return UINT_MAX;
 }

- (id)autorelease {
    return self;
}
```

then when you wish to implement, just:

```
#import "SelectedView.h"
SelectedView *board = [SelectedView instance];

NSInteger integer = board.number;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a Public var/propery e.g. in AppDelegate. 
To Access it:

```
[(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] setN:4];
```